How can I resolve the error when loading a .csv file into a SQL database? I'm receiving an error "Could not open, no such directory or file."
I created a SQL database on my local computer. I created database and tables. I have been trying to upload .csv files to the tables in database. I'm getting the error shown below. Please help me to resolve it. Using PGAdmin and Visual Studio.
Thanks in advance

Could not open file "C:\Users\Emre\Documents\DataAnalytics\SQL_Job_Data_Analysis_Job\csv_files\company_dim.csv" for reading: No such file or directory

I checked the file directory name and location. With using this query it needs to upload the data to the database.
\copy company_dim FROM 'C:\Users\Emre\Documents\Data Analytics\SQL_Job_Data_Analysis_Job\csv_files\company_dim.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true, DELIMITER ',', ENCODING 'UTF8');

I have been using PG Admin 4 and Visual Studio Code
UPDATE: The issue has been resolved. The file location exists, but the file directory included Turkish letters, causing an error.

I checked the file directory name and location Check it again.  That filename does not exist.

Where is the code that you're using to try to upload the file? Is that folder on the same computer that the server is on? Does the user account that the server runs under have access to your personal Documents folder? Have you verified that the file is actually in that specific location and has that exact filename? Also, when asking SQL questions, you need to add a tag for the specific RDBMS that you're using, as syntax and functionality differs between them.

Sorry, I edited my message.
I checked the file directory. It exists on the same computer.
The file name and directory, I verified.

I removed the  tag since this isn't really related to ANSI/ISO SQL. Instead add a tag for the dbms used (Postgresql?)

Could you double-check that the path to company_dim.csv is correct and that the file exists at that location?
Use forward slashes instead of backslashes when specifying the file path in PostgreSQL.
'C:/Users/Emre/Documents/DataAnalytics/SQL_Job_Data_Analysis_Job/csv_files/company_dim.csv'
Please make sure that PostgreSQL has permission to access the directory and read the file. I think you might need to adjust the file permissions to allow access.
Or try to copy .csv to /temp/ directory and check.

